# ICalendar add Attendees

Tags: javascript, icalendar

I have this

```
let data =
        "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" +
        "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\n" +
        "METHOD:PUBLISH\n" +
        "PRODID:-//Send project Invite//EN\n" +
        "VERSION:2.0\n" +
        "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
        "UID:gestionprojectCalendarInvite\n" +
        "DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:" +
        convertDate(startDate) +
        "\n" +
        "DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:" +
        convertDate(endDate) +
        "\n" +
        "SUMMARY:" +
        subject +
        "\n" +
        "DESCRIPTION:" +
        description +
        "\n" +
        "LOCATION:" +
        location +
        "\n" +
        "END:VEVENT\n" +
        "END:VCALENDAR";
```

How can I add attendees to the data that is sent to the calendar event that i'm creating.
Here is the place where I need my info in :
[image: The box]

Comment: I believe outlook only sends a special message type that has the ICS file included, not the other way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added
`ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=NAME_OF_ATTENDEE:mailto:EMAIL_OF_ATTENDEE`
Replace `NAME_OF_ATTENDEE` and `EMAIL_OF_ATTENDEE` with what you need. 
This will put the correct information in the `TO:` box